# Long post title

Tags: css, wordpress

I work on this project http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-polaroid-image-with-css 
Everything's work fine except long post title ( wordpress ). 
Original code:

```
.polaroid-images a:after {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
    content: attr(title);
    position: relative;
    top:15px;
}
```

and I added this:

```
white-space: nowrap;
max-width: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

but text-overflow: ellipsis; not work... Is it possible to do this? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8M8/1/) of the code if anyone wants to help with this, my CSS isn't up to snuff to fix this one.

Comment: thank you very much for JSFoddle code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `display: block` should remedy this.

```
.polaroid-images a:after {
    color: #333;
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
        top: 15px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8M8/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Jrod! This code make a link title short but i will if is it possible to make like a this "Polaroid ima..." It looks a lot better